# How to solve this differential equation numerically?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am solving a rather complex differential equation in 4d space plus time. Here is the Mathematica code to do this:

```
A = 0.05;
B = -0.02;
Cs = 0.03;
Ds = 0.12;
R= -0.3;
τ = 200;
A1[ϕ1_, ϕ2_, ϕ3_, ϕ4_] := (A Sin[ϕ1] - 0.5 UnitStep[t - τ] (t - τ)^2/τ^2 Sin[2 ϕ1] + R Sin[ϕ1 - ϕ3] + 2 R Sin[ϕ1 - ϕ4])
A2[ϕ1_, ϕ2_, ϕ3_, ϕ4_] := (B Sin[ϕ2] - 0.5  UnitStep[t - τ] (t - τ)^2/τ^2 Sin[2 ϕ2] + R Sin[ϕ2 - ϕ3] + 2 R Sin[ϕ2 - ϕ4])
A3[ϕ1_, ϕ2_, ϕ3_, ϕ4_] := (Cs Sin[ϕ3] - 0.5  UnitStep[t - τ] (t - τ)^2/τ^2 Sin[2 ϕ3] + R Sin[ϕ3 - ϕ1] + R Sin[ϕ3 - ϕ2] + 2 R Sin[ϕ3 - ϕ4])
A4[ϕ1_, ϕ2_, ϕ3_, ϕ4_] := (Ds Sin[ϕ4] - 0.5  UnitStep[t - τ] (t - τ)^2/τ^2 Sin[2 ϕ4] + 2 R Sin[ϕ4 - ϕ1] + 2 R Sin[ϕ4 - ϕ2] + 2 R Sin[ϕ4 - ϕ3])

sol = NDSolve[{
    D[P[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4, t], 
      t] == -D[
        A1[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4] P[ϕ1, ϕ2, \
ϕ3, ϕ4, t], ϕ1] - 
      D[A2[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4] P[ϕ1, ϕ2, \
ϕ3, ϕ4, t], ϕ2] D[
        A3[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4] P[ϕ1, ϕ2, \
ϕ3, ϕ4, t], ϕ3] - 
      D[A4[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4] P[ϕ1, ϕ2, \
ϕ3, ϕ4, t], ϕ4] + 
       D[P[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4, t], {ϕ1, 2}] + 
       D[P[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4, t], {ϕ2, 2}] + 
       D[P[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4, t], {ϕ3, 2}] + 
       D[P[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4, t], {ϕ4, 2}],
    P[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4, 0] == 
     1/(0.01 Pi) Exp[-(ϕ1 - Pi/2)^2/
        0.01] Exp[-(ϕ2 - Pi/2)^2/
        0.01] Exp[-(ϕ3 - π/2)^2/
        0.01] Exp[-(ϕ4 - π/2)^2/0.01], 
    P[-π/2, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4, t] == 
     P[3 π/2, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4, t], 
    P[ϕ1, -π/2, ϕ3, ϕ4, t] == 
     P[ϕ1, 3 π/2, ϕ3, ϕ4, t], 
    P[ϕ1, ϕ2, -π/2, ϕ4, t] == 
     P[ϕ1, ϕ2, 3 π/2, ϕ4, t], 
    P[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, -π/2, t] == 
     P[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, 3 π/2, t]}, 
  P[ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3, ϕ4, t], {ϕ1, -Pi/2, 
   3 Pi/2}, {ϕ2, -Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}, {ϕ3, -Pi/2, 
   3 Pi/2}, {ϕ4, -Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}, {t, 0, 400}]
```

If I run this code, I get the following output:

```
At t == 34.87066282375372`, step size is effectively zero; \
singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

and the code stops running. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Note that you cannot use D and C as parameters because these symbols are protected.

Comment: I had those fixed in my code, and have edited the question. The problem persists though.

Comment: I have removed ```/.vals```. `\[Tau]->200` should instead be `\[Tau]=200`, and it comes in definition of `A1, A2..`.

Comment: There is an undifined `J` in the definition of `A2 ` . I think it should be a `R` ?

Comment: Please make sure that your example evaluates correctly in a fresh kernel (i.e. after restarting Mathematica) and produces the error that is claimed.

Comment: Also `α ` is not defined !

Comment: How to check whether there are undefined parameters in the evaluated  "bodyofNDSolve" : Use command `Apply[List, "bodyof NDSolve", \[Infinity]] // Flatten // Variables ` to get `{J, t, \[Alpha], \[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Phi]3, \[Phi]4} ` in your case. Means `J `and `\[Alpha] `are undefined.

Comment: Alright, fixed all the undefined symbols. The error is still the same.